# Instantly search a ListFrament

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a tabbed activity with a `ListFragment` as one of the tabs. The list items are only the contacts that have phone numbers. I want to be able to search it and have the contacts update as the user is searching. Right now the list does not change when searching, I am having trouble figuring out how to filter the results. One weird thing is that I have to programmatically set the query hint because the xml doesn't change it. This is what I have:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".LaunchActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

searchable.xml

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:inputType="textCapWords">
</searchable>
```

menu_launch.xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Contacts.java

```
public class ContactsTab extends ListFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

private CursorAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.contacts_list_item, null, FROM, TO, 0);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryListener);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

private String currentQuery = null;

final private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            currentQuery = null;
        } else {
            currentQuery = newText;
        }
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, ContactsTab.this);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return false;
    }
};


private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
        Contacts._ID,
        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,
        Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
};

private static final String[] FROM = { Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY };
private static final int[] TO = { R.id.contact_text };
private static final String SELECTION = "(" + Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP +
        " = '1' AND (" + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " != 0 ))";

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Uri contentUri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            contentUri,
            PROJECTION,
            SELECTION,
            null,
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " ASC");
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

I really appreciate any help.

EDIT: I believe I have to use `String[] selectionArgs` when loading the cursor, but I have not completely figured it out yet

Comment: read about `Adapter#getFilter()` and `Filter#filter()` method

Comment: I read about filters, but how would I implement that since I don't have an explicit array, I just have the user's contacts?

Comment: see `FilterQueryProvider`